# Transaction created using `bitcoin-cli` failed to decode

Tags: bitcoin-core, createrawtransaction, signrawtransaction

I am creating a rawtransaction using bitcoin-cli. After I create my transaction using 'bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction ' this returns and HEX of:

```
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
```

But then when I try "signrawtransactionwithwallet" this returns TX decode failed. Make sure the tx has at least one input.

bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=$wallet signrawtransactionwithwallet "hex"

How can fix this?

Comment: Please edit your post with the commands you typed. I could decode the transaction you provided using `decoderawtransaction`.

Comment: For the ones who might have same problem this is solved by adding -stdin to the request in command line

Comment: I doubt adding `-stdin` would change anything to the transaction decoding.

Answer (score 1):

Both `decoderawtransaction` and `signrawtransactionwithwallet` on my node managed to decode the transaction. You must have simply made a mistake when copying it.